# HighCharts datetime xAxis without missing values (weekends)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am unable to render datetime chart without weekends. How can one do it?

Here is sample code (http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/1720/):

```
$('#container').highcharts({
  xAxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    ordinal: true,
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      day: '%a'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      [1375221600000, 180.45999999999998],
      [1375308000000, 144.368],
      [1375394400000, 108.27599999999998],
      [1375653600000, 72.184],
      [1375740000000, 36.092],
      [1375826400000, 0]
    ]
  }]
});
```

As you can see, I am trying "ordinal" option from highstocks. You can see in highcharts uservoice, that it could work for highcharts too: "In basic charts it can be enabled by setting ordinal to true." from http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/1089981-allow-irregular-datetime-xaxis-note-irregular-po

So, any suggestions how to remove sunday and saturday from xAxis in HighCharts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Highcharts **doesn't** support ordinal axis. This feature is part of Highstock and require Highstock lbrary to be used. When using Highstock, you are able to create stock charts by calling `new Highstock.StockChart()` and basic charts by callling  `new Highstock.Chart()`.

Comment: Thanks, also got answer in uservoice with working jsfiffdle example http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/LLExL/1732/ :)

Answer (score 1):

Oridinal axis is available only in the Highstock.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal